# Unable to load the markdown code locally using jekyll

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, ubuntu-16.04, jekyll-theme

I am trying to locally host some git-hub pages served using Jekyll. It displays the theme and all, but breaks the place where markdown code is written. Snapshot below:

[image]

A snippet of the markdown code is below:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what might be going wrong?

**System Specs**: Ubuntu 16.04, Jekyll version 2.5, ruby 2.3.lp112

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, your Jekyll version is way too old.
- Secondly, ensure that your page contains front matter dashes at the very top:

  ```
  ---
  title: My Page
  ---

  Page content
  ```
- Then ensure your code-blocks are formatted properly and closed properly:

  ````
  ```<lang>
  <code contents>
  ```
  ````